# Whats the opposite operation for += using strings?

Tags: c#, string

For example I have a

```
String a="Hello";
a+="World";
```

this would put World at the end. How can I put it at the beginning?

Comment: I guess there is no way around using `a = "World" + a`.

Comment: not sure in C#, but if defined for this object, `-=` should be the reverse of `+=`.

Answer (score 11):

Simply:

```
string a = "Hello";
a = "World" + a;
```

Ultimately, `a += "World";` is just abbreviated syntax for:

```
a = a + "World";
```

No such abbreviation exists if you want to reverse the order of the operands.

As a side note - keep in mind that *if you are doing this a lot* (in a loop etc) it may be better to consider `StringBuilder` to avoid lots of intermediary `string`s.

Answer (score 4):

You can also call the Insert function;

```
a = a.Insert(0, "start");
```

Comment: At least this is out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

To prepend, you'd simply use.

```
a = "World" + a;
```

Please bear in mind that actually, you'd be creating a completely new string, you can't pre or postpend any string in C# as they are immutable. Consider using String.Format or StringBuilder.AppendFormat if you have special string processing needs.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
String a = "Hello";
a = "World " + a;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
string a = "Hello";
a = "World" + a;
```

Because `a+= "World";` is equavalent with;

```
a = a + "World";
```

Check out for more information [`How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

**Hint**: This is not in this case but if performance is important, you should always use the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class to concatenate strings. It represents mutable strings.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple you can add the new word in the begin

```
String a="Hello";
a="World" + a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with any special operator. You will have to do:

```
a = "World"+a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder to perform string operations.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: That depends on the scenario; if you are only combining two strings, `+` is more efficient than `StringBuilder`; it *is* appropriate to use `StringBuilder` if you are doing lots of string manipulation, for example in a loop. But saying "Use StringBuilder to perform string operations" is unhelpful (and potentially harmful) advice. Indeed, the best option here is `string a = "Hello" + "World";`, which the ***compiler*** will perform directly - it'll never touch the runtime

Comment: Agree! For less than 4 operation we should avoid Stringbuilder. But the question is nowhere indicating that this is the operation required for single time or multiple time.